# New Google Places Autocomplete is not working?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

i tried to use the new places SDKs from google on adnroid

this is the code i use to launch the intent

i got the code from here

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

It fire the intent with the autocomplete but every time i write something it says:

E/Places: Error while autocompleting: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

I don't understand i have spend all day to make something to work. I tried also the autocomplete fetch place by name but it only returns me results from USA.

Has any of you fellow developers made this to work?
I feel really frustrated right now :)

```
if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
    Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "YOUR_API_KEY");
}


// Set the fields to specify which types of place data to return.
List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, 
Place.Field.NAME);

// Start the autocomplete intent.
Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
        AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields)
        .build(this);
startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 5):

You are supposed to replace "YOUR_API_KEY" with a real key that you got from google when you signed up for a Maps account. I dont know the current license rules for maps, but it used to not be free, if you were using it for things like intranet applications, fleet tracking and other stuff. Or, if you had a lot of traffic.

If you dont provide a real API key, you will only be allowed a few requests, before the limit gets reached.

I assume you have completed this flow: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/places/ so you should have gotten an api key.

Comment: I found a page that shows the costs of the Place API for Autocomplete
https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#ac-per-character

Comment: PS: You have to be careful when using, it seems that the use is by character

Answer (score 3):

you must pay to use
new placeAutoComplete must be used by tokens from google api console
Go to this link : https://console.cloud.google.com/billing
and also if you need to use it just for testing you can change or create api key every time you got this error
let me know if you need anything

Note : when you ready to buy you must know that every on char is a token (type or delete ) because its a request not the full word

Comment: I went back to use Android Geocoder. Back to the basics i guess.